# Where can I find a "how to play" for Game Boy Wars?

Tags: game-boy-wars

I got the Game Boy Wars game, but with no manual or instructions, and I don't know how to use some pieces (like the AA1-COBRA).

Is there a "how to play" or instructions somewhere? I couldn't find it still.

Comment: I made [an English manual for Super Famicom Wars](https://gitlab.com/snippets/5744) a while back, and I've just recently taken interest in playing Game Boy Wars Advance. I'll see if I can't create something equivalent for this game, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game Boy Wars was only released in Japan, so any official documentation is necessarily only in Japanese.

Nintendo of Japan [does have a website](http://www.nintendo.co.jp/n02/dmg/gwj/index.html) about the game, which includes [some basic information](http://www.nintendo.co.jp/n02/dmg/gwj/butai/index.html) on the different unit types. If you don't read Japanese, then this is of course not very useful, although [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) or [Excite Japan](http://www.excite.co.jp/world/english/web/) (pick 日→英) may help.

As an alternative, you may be able to glean enough information from the other titles in the series, such as Famicom Wars, where [GameFAQs has a unit guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/nes/578628-famicom-wars/faqs/39311), or one of the sequels, [Game Boy Wars 3] for the Game Boy Color, where [there are several FAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gbc/582119-gameboy-wars-3/faqs).

If you want any official English material, Nintendo of America has [downloadable manuals](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/manuals/ds.jsp) for the Advance Wars games released for the Nintendo DS, and [replacementdocs](http://replacementdocs.com/download.php?list.8) has manuals for the GBA titles - these games were of course released quite a bit later in the series, and are bound to differ in many ways, but they may still provide enough information to cover your specific problem.